# How can I retrieve a list of Data Extensions in a folder using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I would like to output a list of Data Extension names (and their customer keys) from a specific Data Extension subfolder.

Is this possible using SSJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is actually relatively simple. You just use the [DataExtension.Retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRetrieve.htm) function and use the filter of 'CategoryID'.

See below sample:

```
var results = DataExtension.Retrieve({Property:"CategoryID",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:95303});
```

Where 95303 is the folder id. (categoryid)

This will return a JSON with each of the DEs in that folder.

If you are unsure how to get this ID, you can get it via a few API calls or the simpler way is to hover over the folder in SFMC UI and you will see the 'CategoryID' listed in the path at the bottom left.
[image]

You can also get it from Developer tools in the 'Network' tab.
[image]